# How can I print the name of object using a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I am new to java so I am just wondering, how I can loop through my `Set` and print their names. My question is mostly based around how I can loop through the objects as I am unsure.

The reason I can confused is because if  you look at `testingProgram.java`. the first line is `Set<Fruit> fruit1 = new ArrayListSet<Fruit>();`. The type of `fruit1` is `Set<Fruit>`. I am use to seeing the something like this `ArrayListSet<Fruit> fruit1 = new ArrayListSet<Fruit>();`. Where the type of `fruit1` is actually `ArrayListSet<Fruit>`. So how do I loop through it?

My question is in the `printStuff()` function in the `ArrayListSet.java` file.

---

testingProgram.java

```
Set<Fruit> fruit1 = new ArrayListSet<Fruit>();
fruit1.add(new Apple("Gala"));
fruit1.add(new Apple("Fuji"));
fruit1.add(new Orange("Navel"));

Set<Fruit> fruit2 = new ArrayListSet<Fruit>();
fruit2.add(new Apple("Red Apple"));
fruit2.add(new Apple("Yellow Apple"));
fruit2.add(new Orange("Small Orange"));

fruit2.printStuff(fruit1);
```

---

ArrayListSet.java

```
public class ArrayListSet<E> implements Set<E> {

    private ArrayList<E> elements;

    public ArrayListSet() {
        elements = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(E e) {
        if (!elements.contains(e))
            elements.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(E e) {
        elements.remove(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object e) {
        return elements.contains(e);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return elements.size();
    }

    public void printAllFruitNames(Set<?> printMe) {
        // How do I print the names of the supplied parameter (printMe)
    }
```

---

Apple.java

```
public class Apple implements Fruit {

    private String name;

    public Apple(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

---

Orange.java

```
public class Orange implements Fruit {

    private String name;

    public Orange(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

---

Fruit.java

```
public interface Fruit {
    public String getName();
}
```

---

Set.java

```
public interface Set<E> extends Iterable<E> {


    public void add(E e);


    public void remove(E e);


    public boolean contains(Object e);


    public int size();

}
```

Comment: Which part don't you get? How to loop through a `Set`? How to get the fruits name by calling `getName()`? How to print a value? Can't be all 3, so try something. It's how to learn!!

Comment: @Andreas How to loop through `Set`. Because set has an `Apple` object and an `Orange` Object.

Comment: Why is the print method of your set taking another set as parameter? Shouldn't it print itself?

Comment: @Andreas I know its kind of stupid but I am just trying to understand how to print the set. that you get in the parameter

Comment: No it doesn't. It has two `Fruit` objects. Sure, one is an `Apple` and the other an `Orange`, but the set doesn't know that, and doesn't care.

Comment: @Andreas so how can I loop through them.

Comment: @Andreas `for (Type singleObject : printMe) {}` ? What is the type I put to loop through the `Set`

Comment: @Mick The same type as the `Set`, what else? `Fruit`!! That is what the set contains, so that is what you're iterating.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to doing that

1) Since the parameter to the printAllFruitNames is Set, while iterating through the Set, each element should be handled by an Object type(corresponding to ?) and then after casting the object to Fruit the printName method can be called on the object. Like this.

```
for(Object obj :printMe) {
            if(obj instanceof Fruit)// Checking if this is an instance of Fruit before invoking getName() method
                System.out.println(((Fruit)obj).getName())
        }
```

2) Overrride the toString method in Apple and Orange

like this

```
 public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
```

and in printAllFruitNames the for loop will be

```
for(Object obj :printMe) {
            System.out.println(obj)
        }
```

Printing the object will just invoke the toString() method in the incoming object. 
This approach doesn't require any type checking whether it is Fruit type or not.

Answer (score -1):

Using Object in for.
When I am right what you are thinking about then you have to loop through the Set as an Object iterator.

```
set.stream().forEach(loop -> System.out.println(((Fruit) loop).getName());
```

Actually, you should check if the loop object is an instance of Fruit before casting the Fruit Object.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this using a for loop. Like `for (Type singleObject : printMe) {}`. This is because I want to add if statements and what not inside the loop.

Comment: BTW, you can skip `.stream()` going directly to `.forEach()`, ie `set.forEach(...)`. Also, if the set’s type is known, you won’t need the cast either.

Comment: Why would you need to cast to `Fruit` when the set is already declared to be a set of fruits? --- Also, for question from a newbie who doesn't understand even a `for` loop over a set, *streams* are may out of scope, so this answer is not useful.

Comment: First of all the generic is set to Unknown <?> in the method print, to be sure that no errors can be thrown we use "instance of" to check if the looped object is a Fruit.

Comment: I don't know if you already got the right question @Mick

Use 

`for (Object loop : printMe) if (loop instanceof Fruit) System.out.printIn(((Fruit) loop).getName());`